# Float Aside next to a Section HTML5

Tags: html, css-float

I am trying to get an Aside tag to float next to a Section tag with CSS but not having much luck so far.

Below is the HTML

```
<div id="WholePage">
<section> 
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContentWindow" runat="server">                 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</section>

<aside>
    <div id="SideAdRotator">
    <asp:AdRotator ID="AsideAdRotator" runat="server" AdvertisementFile="Adverts.xml"         Height="300px" Width="150px"/>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Below is the CSS so far

```
section
{
    display : block;
    width : 48em;
    height : 40em;
    border-width : 0.1em;
    border-style : dashed;
    border-color : black;
}

aside
{
    display : block;
    width : 12em;
    height : 40em;
    border-width : 0.1em;
    border-style : dashed;
    border-color : black;
}
```

Any suggestions or advice on how to get this would be greatly appreciated. First time Ive ever had this issue of floating sections so really stumped as to why now.

Many thanks to all the responses, they have all been useful and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to both elements.

Don't forget to [clear your floats](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I should change the order of the tags and give them `display: inline-block;`

The other answers about float I should not use. Most designers misunderstand float.

[When use float?](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/)

## Html

```
<div id="WholePage">
    <aside></aside>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
section
{
    display : inline-block;
    width : 48em;
    height : 40em;
    border-width : 0.1em;
    border-style : dashed;
    border-color : black;
}

aside
{
    display : inline-block;
    width : 12em;
    height : 40em;
    border-width : 0.1em;
    border-style : dashed;
    border-color : black;
}
```

[Example @ jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL4Gk/1/)

Comment: Thank You for the two links provided. The when to use float is most useful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left` to your `aside` and `section`.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `float: left;` to your `<aside>` section.

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary to wrap the elements...

**CSS**

```
#WholePage {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  padding: 10px;
}
section {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
aside {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

[example @ fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Waschak/Leuh5von/)